# Printing ArrayCollection in Text Fields in FLex

Tags: php, apache-flex

I am getting the the output in Flex from PHP as...

```
    appSes = new ArrayCollection (ArrayUtil.toArray(event.result));
```

I need the value to be stored in textInput...

```
<mx:TextInput id="keyword" styleName="glass" width="100%"/>
```

How to ??

Comment: Wait... What? You want to assign the value of an ArrayCollection to a TextInput??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join the array and display it in the keyword text field

```
<mx:TextInput id="keyword" styleName="glass" width="100%" text="{appSes.source.join(',')}" />
```

But appSes must be a class property and declared as [Bindable] for this to work, or you can just assign it after you create the new ArrayCollection

```
appSes = new ArrayCollection(ArrayUtil.toArray(event.result));
keyword.text = appSes.source.join(',');
```

I hope this is what you wanted

Answer (score -1):

You can bind to the text property of the TextInput:

```
<mx:TextInput id="keyword" styleName="glass" width="100%" text="{appSes}"/>
```

(Not sure why you would want to do this though)